# create json object from html select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select

I want to create a json string which contains all select values and inner html values as a map;
Eg:

```
<select id="my-select">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>

var jsonObject = //..... process of creating json object...

var finalString ="";

for(key in jsonObject ){

finalString= finalString +key+":"+jsonObject[key];

}

alert(finalString);
```

finalString should be 1:one2:two

All I need is **//..... process of creating json object...**.
Your help is really appreciated

Thank You !

Comment: I think you want a normal javascript object, not JSON. What exactly are you having problems with? Selecting the options? Creating an object? Adding properties to an object? All of these have been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ordinary Javascript object. JSON is what you use when you want to convert a Javascript object to a string, so you can send it over the network.

```
var javascriptObject = {};
$("#my-select option").each(function() {
    javascriptObject[this.value] = $(this).text();
}
```